# English as a system language but Russian regional settings

Tags: language-support, locale

I usually choose English as an installation language since I believe that the original is better than the translation. However, the environment I'm working in is mostly Russian, so I have to deal with locale specificity.

Even worse is the fact that selecting English yields to royal measurement system, that is, feet, inches, and damned `letter` paper size. Whatever I do, I didn't manage to get rid of `letter` paper size - eventually here and there I stumble upon `letter` as a hidden default, and that spoils my prints.

How can I select and use English as my language, but use metric system everywhere and `a4` paper size everywhere, and Russian regional settings (date, time, decimal etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you execute `locale` you can see the language variables that are used for various sections of the operating system:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

More about locale variables in the gettext manual: [Locale Environment Variables - GNU `gettext' utilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Locale-Environment-Variables.html)

You can export these variables e.g. `export LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"` - this will make a temporary change.

If you want to make it permanent you can change the regional formats using `gnome-language-selector`. Or you can add the export command in ~/.profile and/or ~/.bashrc

For the papersize, I found that you can edit `/etc/papersize` - change "letter" to "a4".
You might also need to set `export LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF_8"` (or maybe `export LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF_8"` if ru_RU defaults to A4)

Source: [answers.launchpad.net: Question #6846 : Questions : “evince” package : Ubuntu](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+question/6846)

P.S. Personally I use en_GB (English / United Kingdom) for everything since it uses the SI metric system instead of American English and US units.

Comment: Problem is that `/etc/papersize` works only for those programs that use `libpaper` or read and honor it. For example, `OpenOffice` ignores this file. Also, `gnome-language-selector` is only relevant to `gnome` environment.

Comment: **1.** Fair enough, but I believe I gave alternatives. **2.** I don't know about OpenOffice, does this happen with LibreOffice too? **3.** Maybe there's no way to set it in *Office, but there was no feature request about locale paper size support. Have you filed a bug/feature request upstream? **4.** Instead of gnome-language-selector you can set your locale-related variables in ~/.profile /etc/profile or `/etc/environment` if the profile files don't do the trick. **5.** gnome-language-selector works in gnome 2/3 and unity AFAIK. You could mention which desktop manager you use. :)

Comment: All 1-4 agreed. As for 5: since Unity and since gnome2 is no more, I prefer using xfce/lxde.

Comment: @mbaitoff editing `/etc/default/locale` did the trick for me

Comment: @Alexander Malakhov: what kind of edits did you introduce in the file?

Comment: @mbaitoff: I had a single line in it `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`, and all other settings defaulted to that locale. The only thing I wanted different was weeks to start from monday (not sunday). So I added `LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"` (I didn't have Russian locale installed). All parameters' names should be the same as what you get from `locale` command. Or you can just try en_GB locale (change `LANG` value) as medigeek suggests.

Answer (score 0):

> Whatever I do, I didn't manage to get rid of letter paper size -
>   eventually here and there I stumble upon letter as a hidden default,
>   and that spoils my prints.

There are 2 locale settings. Settings of whole system and settings of **LibreOffice**.

1) Please find option **Language Support** in your OS. There will be 2 tabs: 1st - Language; 2nd - **Regional formats**. It is setting for currency, number and date format in Russian. Let choose Russian than click **Apply System-Wide** button. Reboot or restart.

2) LibreOffice have own locale/size settnigs. In LibreOffice menu: Tools → Options → Language settings → Languages → **Locale settings** → Russian. 
Also! Tools → Options → LibreOffice → General → **Measurement unit** → cm (instead inch)

Reboot or restart LibreOffice.

Answer (score 0):

in the console run
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure locale`
and choose what you need